# Check whether memory address can be accessed from linux kernel space

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

without entering too much in details, I'm writing this device driver for an fpga pci board, DMA-capable.
There is a situation where the board dma-writes an ACK in memory with some data. This data is actually a pointer to a struct in memory i previously allocated, the pointer is notified to the board by using registers. So, I use the data written by the board to dereference a memory region. 
Since we are still in the debugging stage for this board, I cannot be totally sure about the data DMA-written, so it happens to de-reference an invalid pointer (because the data DMA-written are inconsistent).

**My question is:** is there a way to check a memory pointer (from kernel space) before accessing it, without generate invalid access and/or a kernel panic?

Comment: What about checking PTE & PTE flags?

Comment: Instead of using absolute memory addresses (which you don't know how to easily validate), consider using indices or relative memory addresses (which can be validated).

Answer (score 1):

On a 32 bit system, the virtual memory addressing is diveded in the following way

```
0x00000000             0xc0000000  0xffffffff 
    |                        |          |
    +------------------------+----------+
    |  User                  |  Kernel  |
    |  space                 |  space   |
    +------------------------+----------+
```

So if I'm not wrong, you could always check whether your pointer is inside the following range (which is low memory)

```
0xc0000000 - 0xffffffff
3'221'225'472 - 4'294'967'295
```

But I'm not a linux-kernel expert, so it might be there are better and safer ways to achieve this

Comment: I think this will not solve my problem... this is useful to check if an address is "valid" for kernel space, but if I de-reference a pointer to a "valid" virtual address, which could be potentially not translated into a valid physical one, I will obtain an invalid memory access...

Comment: The functions in <asm/io.h> will give you a virtual-to-physical translation (see http://www.tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/devices/addrxlate.html), but I'm not sure if you can use that to check if an address is allocated... Since this is for debugging, could you just store a global list of all your allocations and check it before de-referencing a pointer?